# UIPickerView in UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, xcode6, uialertcontroller

In iOS8 one has to use `UIAlertController` instead of `UIAlertView`. I wanted to ask if you can add a `UIPickerView` to the AlertController's view. I've already tried to do this and the PickerView was even added but the view hasn't been scaled up so that the picker view was just above the AlertController. Would be great if someone could help me :] Answer would be both in Swift or Objective-C great.

Comment: Seems strange to add a picker to an alert view. Is there another component you can use? Do you have a picture of the UI you're creating?

Comment: I found a good idea on Stackoverflow, kind of a hack - when I set the message to some \n\n... there is enough space to add a picker to the AlertController's view

Answer (score 0):

The reference doc reads that:

"The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."

Comment: Well, okay then.. but is there a nicer way to do this than adding a simple UIView with the picker on it to the view?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a few items in your UIPicker, you could try to migrate to an UIAlertController with UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet style

```
UIAlertController(title: <#String?#>, message: <#String?#>, preferredStyle: <#UIAlertControllerStyle#>)
UIAlertAction(title: <#String#>, style: <#UIAlertActionStyle#>, handler: <#((UIAlertAction!) -> Void)!##(UIAlertAction!) -> Void#>)
```

---

@OliverBorchert
Otherwise you should have a look at
https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0